Exposing 11434 port in Docker container to access Ollama local model
I am trying to connect local Ollama 2 model, that uses port 11434 on my local machine, with my Docker container running Linux Ubuntu 22.04. I can confirm that Ollama model definitely works and is accessible through http://localhost:11434/. In my Docker container, I am also running GmailCTL service and was able to successfully connect with Google / Gmail API to read and send emails from Google account. Now I want to wait for an email and let the LLM answer the email back to the sender. However, I am not able to publish the 11434 port in order to connect model with container.
I tried setting up devcontainer.json file to forward the ports:
{ "name": "therapyGary", "build": { "context": "..", "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile" }, "forwardPorts": [80, 8000, 8080, 11434] }
I tried exposing the ports in the Dockerfile:
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 11434`
These seem to add the ports to the container and Docker is aware of them, but when I check the port status for the currently used image, I get this message:
"Error: No public port '11434' published for 5ae41009199a"
I also tried setting up the docker-compose.yaml file:
services: my_service: image: 53794c7c792c # Replace with your actual Docker image name ports: - "11434:11434" - "8000:8000" - "8080:8080" - "80:80"
But there seems to be a problem with it, where any container with it automatically stops.
I tried stopping the Ollama model, before running the container as to not create a conflict, but that did not help either. Any suggestions are very welcome.
Thanks!
-- edit -- adding Dockerfile code:
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV GMAILCTL_VERSION=0.10.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
python3 
python3-pip 
xdotool 
curl 
software-properties-common 
libreoffice 
unzip 
&& apt-get clean
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib pandas requests
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devuser
RUN mkdir -p /workspace && chown -R devuser:devuser /workspace
USER root
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . .
RUN chown -R devuser:devuser /workspace
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 11434
CMD [ "bash" ]

So it sounds like you’ve got the LLM running on your host machine, right? What the expose command does is open the port in the container, so you’re opening the port in the container, where the model isn’t running. You’d need to change the network on the container to HOST, so it can see services running on your local network, and have it connect to the OLLAMA port, not expose it in the container. In order to tell you how to do that, we’d need to see what container you’re trying to run.

Yes that's correct, the LLM is running on my local Windows machine and I was trying to connect to it from my Docker container running Linux. Your answer did make me think however, why not simply run the LLM within the container, which I did and it solved the issue. However, I would still be interested in solving this problem "the hard way" just for the sake of learning a new trick (if that's not too much trouble!). I edited original post to contain the Dockerfile. Thanks!

One curious question: Since you have ran your chatbot application inside the Docker Container, did you also pull the Ollama Models (like Mistral:latest, or nomic-embed-text:latest) inside the docker container?
If yes, then i would like to know how did you achieve this.

Yes, pulling the Ollama model inside the Docker container was the key solution to my issue. I used this command: ollama run llama2 where "llama2" is just an example of a model. It automatically downloads and runs the given model and lets you interact with it inside the container.

So remove the EXPOSE 11434 statement, what that does is let you connect to a service in the docker container using that port. 11434 is running on your host machine, not your docker container.
To let the docker container see port 11434 on your host machine, you need use the host network driver, so it can see anything on your local network. To do this, you can use the runArgs parameter:
{ "name": "therapyGary", 
"build": 
  { "context": "..", 
    "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile" 
  }, 
"forwardPorts": [80, 8000, 8080, 11434] 
}

would become
{ "name": "therapyGary", 
"build": 
  { "context": "..", 
    "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile" 
  }, 
"runArgs": ["--net=host"]
}

Then, from within your container, you should be able to contact the LLM on port 11434 by referencing localhost or 127.0.0.1 from your container. E.g. in netcat nc localhost 11434. If you're using Docker Desktop, you need to enable host networking by going into Features in development tab in Settings and select the Enable host networking option, per the documentation here: Docker Desktop
As a side note, you can use --net=host or --network=host, both work on my machine using Windows 11 and Docker Desktop.
If you want to use a docker compose yaml file, you would use the network_mode parameter:
services: 
  my_service: 
    image: 53794c7c792c 
    # Replace with your actual Docker image name 
    network_mode: "host"

Because you're putting the container on the host network, there is no need to expose ports, since it's like plugging your container directly into your network. See the Note in the documentation.
References:
Dev Container Image Specific Properties
Docker Engine Host Network Driver Reference

Thank you so much halldk, everything now works as expected. Couldn't have made it without you!

Happy to help! Would you mind marking this as the accepted answer? @PiotrGrochowski

If you are on Windows 11 use http://host.docker.internal:11434 as the Base URL on your connection credentials for your Ollama account.

